# escaped to php inside html - getting dropped back to html by "->"

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am sure this is a trivial matter but I can't seem to get my head around it.

I am entering the below code into a K2 article in joomla.

```
<?php if($cleengApi->isAccessGranted($offerId)): ?>
    <img src="images/myImage.png" alt="" />
<?php else: ?> more code...
```

My problem is I get dropped back into html when the parser reaches the `->` part. So the result is `isAccessGranted($offerId)): ?>` printed on screen. As if the `>` actually ends the php escape sequence. Is there a clever way to escape the escape character or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->` will not drop you back to HTML.

The only explanation that I can think of for this is that your PHP isn't being processed by the PHP engine at all.

This will cause `<?php` to be treated by the browser as an unrecognized tag. The `>` will then end that tag.

In general, you need to make sure:

- You are running an HTTP server
- You have PHP installed for that server
- The file the PHP code is in is one that the server is configured to send to the PHP parser
- You are loading the document from the HTTP server (with a URL starting with `http://` or `https://`) and not directly from your file system

However you said:

> I am entering the below code into a K2 article in joomla.

This suggests that you are typing the code into some kind of data file that Joomla will read. Joomla may not expect that data file to include PHP code and thus won't parse any PHP in it.

Comment: Nothing to make sure here, it is simply not permitted to do php in such an article.

Comment: That certainly explains a whole lot. I did not think to check I just assumed that since I can use html then php would be fine as well. My mistake. Thanks for your help!